# didSelectCustomPOI is fired only when the map is zoomed in

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps, callouts

When tapping on a custom poi on the map, a`calloutView` should appear. 
The`didSelectCustomPOI` delegate method gets executed and the`calloutView` appears only when the map is zoomed in very close to the custom poi.

I'm getting this issue since i've updated the Skobbler sdk to 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

See the [annotationTapZoomLimit](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.4.0/Classes/SKMapSettings.html#//api/name/annotationTapZoomLimit) property - by default it is set to zoom level 12 - most likely this is stopping you from tapping the annotations (decrease it to enable interactions at lower zoom levels)

Comment: SKMapSettings *mapSettings = [SKMapSettings mapSettings];
    mapSettings.annotationTapZoomLimit = 2;

I've added these lines of code, but the problem isn't solved yet

Comment: Hmm… the other thing I can think of is the "click" area – it could be that there is a difference between what "clickable" area you are seeing and what is actually clickable.

Could you send to dev(at)skobbler.com the code & artefacts you are using as annotation icons? (views, how you create annotations, map settings).

Comment: 2.5 years old solution, but it saved me today! +1 for the question and +1 for the answer.